# How to copy specific cells from each row in another sheet if certain condition is met?

Tags: excel, vba

So my problem is this. I have a workbook with lets say 2 sheets. I have automatically created sheet2 from another program and sheet1 where I would like only some of the information from sheet2.

I am now trying to create a macro that would check each row starting from 14 with the value in E% greater than 15. If the condition is met I would like the macro to copy cell value from C% and E% to sheet1 lets say in A5 and B5 and then proceed to next row in sheet2 pasting the valued to A6 B6 and so on.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Variant


    With Sheets("Sheet2")


        lastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("E14:E" & lastRow)


        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value > 15 Then
            'And here is where it gets bugged. I know theres something wrong with the .select but I couldnt think of any other way to
            'pick only just the 2 cells needed.
                Range(cell.Offset(0, -1), cell.Offset(0, 0)).Select
                Selection.Copy

                'In here there should also be some code to select where to place the copyed
                'data but since it already got bugged couldnt really find a solution for 
                'it..
                Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select

            End If
        Next
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: sooo where are you with that? what have you tried and what errors are you running into? Nobody is going to code your macro for you, but post your code and tell us what errors you're seeing and we'll help you through

Comment: yeah sorry my bad.. got the original code there in a sec

Comment: hmm so what seems to happen? When i run the code it doesnt really fail at all. is it getting stuck when the cells are blank? or when they are text instead of numbers? I pasted various numbers in column e in rows 14 through 28 and it looped through all of them. cell was set properly, it selected cell in column e and the one to the left of that (column d, if you want to select to the right, use positive numbers in the `offset`) it copied the selection, it activated sheet1 (although i'd use `.activate` instead) and it pasted, then went back to sheet2

Comment: rather than select / copy, you could try `Range(cell.Offset(0, -1), cell.Offset(0, 0)).copy` and when pasting, you'd want to actually have it select where to paste, so after activating the target sheet, you'd wanna have like `Range("a5", "b5").pasteSpecial`. you'd use `PasteSpecial` as range object do not support the paste method, and activesheet.paste only really works if you're just pasting in like A1 or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I guess i'll put it together:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Variant
dim count as long
count = 0

With Sheets("Sheet2")


    lastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("E14:E" & lastRow)


    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > 15 Then
        'And here is where it gets bugged. I know theres something wrong with the         .select but I couldnt think of any other way to
        'pick only just the 2 cells needed.
            Range(cell.Offset(0, -1), cell.Offset(0, 0)).Select
            Selection.Copy
        'maybe use: Range(cell.Offset(0, -1), cell.Offset(0, 0)).copy


            'In here there should also be some code to select where to place the copyed
            'data but since it already got bugged couldnt really find a solution for 
            'it..
            Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            Range("A5", B5).offset(count, 0).PasteSpecial 'this will make it so that it starts in a5, and moves down a row each time
            count = count + 1            'dont forget to increment count

            Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

        End If
    Next
End With


End Sub
```

and that's kinda a rough thing..

you might include some error handling like: `if not cell.value = "" then` or also `if not isNumeric(cell.value) then` and those together would ensure you're only processing non blank cells with numbers.

Comment: Thank you sir. With a little bit of tweaking I got it work just perfectly. Its good to have someone help with fresh brains. Mine are so overcooked from today that couldnt get a single thought out today and deadlines pushing in 3h..

Comment: If a cell is numeric, it cannot be blank. It has to contain a number for Excel to consider it numeric, so you only need one check ;)